# Layer list Custom Drawable not working in Android versions below Marshmallow?

Tags: android, size, version, layer-list, android-custom-drawable

I am using a drawable in the left of a text view to set the icon of my contact number. The custom drawable that I created works perfectly in android versions Marshmallow or greater but below that it is producing no effect and the icon appears large. What can I do to make it work in other versions as well?

`My custom_drawable_phone.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item
       android:id="@+id/notification"
       android:drawable="@drawable/ic_phone"
        android:width="16dp"
        android:height="16dp">
     </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: As for the size, you should set it in the ic_phone drawable itself and not the layer list. If you are using a pre-made vector you may not be able to change it in the xml but if you can create the drawable with asset studio from an SVG and you can override the size upon creation.